# Update checkbox options using ajax in Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, forms

A little explanation of the app. It's a tour registration system for a multi-campus organization. Someone should be able to come in and select a campus from a select box and have the "options" checkboxes and "tour dates" radio buttons update to be campus specific.

I've got the script triggering when someone changes the select box but it keeps returning a 404 when I go to the path and the url looks really wonky. Also I know I'm going to run into trouble when I try to .html replace the section with new options. Ok without further ado, here's the code. Any guidance would be appreciated!

## _form.html.erb

```
...
<div class="field">
    <%= label_tag 'Campus' %>
    <%= select_tag 'campuses', options_from_collection_for_select(@churches, 'id', 'name', selected: (@registration.event.church.id unless @registration.event.nil?) )%>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= label_tag 'Areas of Interest' %>
    <div id="options_container">
        <%= f.collection_check_boxes :option_ids, @options, :id, :ministry_area do |b| %>
        <div class="collection-check-box">
            <%= b.check_box %>
            <%= b.label %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= label_tag 'Tour Dates' %>
    <div id="events_container">
        <%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:event_id, @events, :id, :event_datetime) do |b| %>
        <div class="radio">
            <%= b.radio_button + " " + b.label %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit params[:action] == 'edit' ? "Update Registration" : "Register", class: 'button' %>
</div>
<% end %>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#campuses').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<%= update_campus_options_and_events_path %>",
                data: {
                    campus_id: $('#campuses').val()
                },
                dataType: "script"
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

## routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :registrations
  root 'registrations#index'
  get 'update_campus_options_and_events', to: 'registrations#update_campus_options_and_events'
end
```

## registrations_controller.rb

```
...
  def update_campus_options_and_events
    @events = Event.find(params[:campus_id])
    @options = Option.find(params[:campus_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js {}
    end
  end
...
```

## update_campus_options_and_dates.js.erb

```
console.log('Options changed via ajax');
$('#options_container').html("<%= escape_javascript(<%= f.collection_check_boxes :option_ids, @options, :id, :ministry_area do |b| %>) %>");
$('#events_container').html("<%= escape_javascript(<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:event_id, @events, :id, :event_datetime) do |b| %>) %>");
```